# No Action Needed + I'm Done simultaneously enabled in Late Answers review queue when I have already acted on that post

Tags: bug, review, late-answers

Happens (spurious only, couldn't find a pattern) when I had already acted on a post before I review it in the queue, [last seen after flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/2573690)

[image]

concededly minor, just slightly irritating

**Update**

Feels really weird if it happens [in an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/2590195): I was pretty sure I hadn't seen the answer today ....