# Remove/blur the "I'm done" message while auditing users on review

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

Stack Exchange sites have an audit feature to test a reviewer for his/her concentration, while generating the review test questions remove the "I'm done" button doesn't get blurred, why don't we blur it as usual?

For example while accessing my review queue today on Super User I got this post and the "I'm done" button doesn't get blurred, is it bug?

For more clarification I have enclosed the image :

[image]

Usually the "I'm done" button will pop up when the reviewer makes any changes to the question or answer, here I didn't make any changes with respect to the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding.  When you first get the audit question, the I'm Done button is enabled immediately?

Comment: maybe the moderators decided first post audits were too hard and started giving off subtle hints for those who do care about their reviews.

Comment: @psubsee2003 yup exactly ,whenever i get the audit testing question,i'm done button is enabled immediately

Comment: this seems to happen when having interacted with the post _before_ seeing it in the review queue, [posted as bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190100/159794) a while ago - though my take is that the bug is enabling both no-action and done button at the same time