# First post Review

Tags: discussion, review

I already flagged this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94199/insert-text-in-adpush-block) as low quality and also when I reviewed the same post in **First post Review** queue, **I'm Done** button is disabled, Instead **No Action Needed** Button is enabled, Is this normal ? finally I clicked the Skip button.

[image]

Comment: Did you flag it from the queue or on the question itself?

Comment: I flag it from the question not in the review queue

Comment: Review has its own scope. Flagging outside the review scope is a not considered a review action.

Comment: related (not a dupe): [Flagging VLQ after opening the post in Low Quality queue but prior to recommending deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204694/flagging-vlq-after-opening-the-post-in-low-quality-queue-but-prior-to-recommendi)

Comment: hmm ... never seen (on SO) the done-button disabled when I acted on a post off a queue, quite the contrary: [often both nothing-needed and done are enabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190100/159794)

Comment: @kleopatra Perhaps theres a race condition somewhere; if you interact with the question before it enters the queue the queue realises, if not it doesn't. Or vice versa

Answer (score 3):

"No action needed" is enabled until you have made an action **within the queue**

This is an unusual situation where you have already taken all the action you wish to on a question before seeing it in the queue. In this case "skip" is the appropriate action to take as "no action needed" signals to the system that the post is fine (which you clearly do not think) and may lead to the question leaving the queue.

Arguably it would be good to have the post simply not shown to you at all, however, this comes up rarely and pressing "skip" is equivalent.

Comment: actually, that's not what I'm seeing (doing reviewing off and on the late answer queue) - after having acted on a post, then seeing it in the queue, the done is enable always, occasionally the no-action as well